# Обертывание определённых слов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В данном примере я хочу в тексте выделить слова `"true"` и `"false"` синим цветом и изменить размер шрифта. Использую функцию `.wrap()`, но ничего не получается. В массив слова `"true"` и `"false"`, обернутые HTML-кодом, не записываются.

CSS:

```
.a {
    color: #00F;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button>OK</button>
<p id="p1">Hello World true Привет Мир false Hello World true Привет Мир false</p>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //записываем текст в переменную, превращаем строку в массив, в качестве
    //разделителя - пробел
    var str = $('#p1').text().split(' ');
    //создаем пустой массив
    var ara = [];
    for (var i in str) {
        if (str[i] == 'true' || str[i] == 'false') {
            var a = str[i];
            //двойное обертывание, что бы получить HTML код, а не текст
            var b = $(a).wrap('<div class="b"><span class="a"></span></div>');
            //записываем полученный HTML код в массив
            ara[i] = $('.b').html();
        } else {
            ara[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    $('button').css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' }).click(function () {
        //превращает массив в строку, в качестве разделителя — пробел
        $('#p2').text(ara.join(' '));
    });
});
```

Теоретически, во второй параграф, при нажатии на кнопку, должен быть записан такой текст:

```
Hello World <span class="a">true</span> Привет Мир <span class="a">false</span> Hello World <span class="a">true</span> Привет Мир <span class="a">false</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Код несколько переусложнён. В частности, с лишними оборачиванием и разворачиванием.
- Для `#p2` стоит использовать `.html()`, а не `.text()`, чтобы вставить именно HTML-код.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = $('#p1').text().split(' ');
    var ara = [];
    for (var i in str) {
        var a = str[i];
        if (a == 'true' || a == 'false') {
            ara[i] = '<span class="a">' + a + '</span>';
        } else {
            ara[i] = a;
        }
    }
    $('button').css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' }).click(function () {
        $('#p2').html(ara.join(' '));
    });
});
```

```css
.a {
    color: #00F;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>OK</button>
<p id="p1">Hello World true Привет Мир false Hello World true Привет Мир false</p>
<p id="p2"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Но, мне интересно, как это выполнить с помощью функции wrap(). Я начал изучать jQuery. Вот в чем дело.

Comment: @Sergey конкретные слова в строке текста? Никак. `.wrap()` не для этого используется. Важно использовать нужные средства в конкретной задаче.

Comment: Все, я понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @Sergey на здоровье.